# How to Kill Java Update?

Tags: windows, java, updates

I've got rid of the auto-update for Java by disabling it through the registry. Is there a way to stop people from manually updating Java? If someone tries to update Java through other means, is there a way I can stop it from running?

Comment: People? Are you talking about a domain or workgroup? I assume Java is needed or just uninstall it. It's a huge security risk not running the latest version. You can disable Java it in the browser via Control Panel>Java>Security

Comment: I'm assuming you are on windows. if the user can update java (which by default exists in program files) then they have the ability to become an admin via uac, so no, there is little-to-nothing you can do to constrain them. if you are on a domain, GPOs may be able to assert some control, but it will be iffy.

Comment: Why would you disable the abilit to update Java?  Doing that only leaves the user vulerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"%PROGRAMFILES%\Java\jre7\bin\jqs.exe" -unregister
msiexec /qn /x {4A03706F-666A-4037-7777-5F2748764D10}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain to me how this works? I just want to know for future situations

Comment: what is the difference between your command prompt line and this one:
"msiexec /x {4A03706F-666A-4037-7777-5F2748764D10} /qn"?

Comment: @Ochan Reversed only arguments msiexec. Action teams will be no different.